# Dual of a $\mathbb{C}G$-module, can we get $g^{-1}$ outside $\theta(\cdot)$?

Tags: modules, representation-theory, dual-spaces

I am a bit lost with dual modules.

Let $G$ be a group, $\mathbb{C}$ be the complex numbers and let $V$ be a $\mathbb{C}G$-module. Then as I understand it, the dual is $V^*=\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}G}(C,\mathbb{C}G)$. So if we have $\theta\in V^*$ the action is given by $(g\cdot \theta)(v)=\theta(g^{-1}\cdot v)=g^{-1}\theta(v)$ where after the last equality we get the product inside $\mathbb{C}G$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the dual of a $kG$-module, and the dual of an $R$-module, where $R=kG$. If $R$ is a ring and $M$ is a right $R$-module, then the dual of $M$, $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,R)$, is a left $R$-module.

This is **not** the same as the dual of a right (or left) $kG$-module, which is the dual of $M$ as a vector space $\mathrm{Hom}_k(M,k)$, with the group action as you have described, notably on the same side as the original action.

There are two different concepts, one used in representation theory of groups and one used in module theory for arbitrary rings.

Comment: Though, to be fair, one should note that the two concepts are still very closely related concepts. Since group rings give us the luxury of switching between left- and right-modules (and one could argue that this switch has already happened because of the occurrence of $g^{-1}$ in the definition of the dual representation), it still makes sense (and is in fact true) to say that these two constructions are naturally isomorphic.

Comment: Oh, no wonder I am confused. Actually I can't even find the definition of the dual of a kG-module on wikipedia

Comment: @roi_saumon You need to look for dual representation, not dual module.

Comment: Actually the two notions are the same: one has a natural isomorphism of right $kG$-modules $Hom_k(V,k)\to Hom_{kG}(V,kG)$ given by $\varphi\mapsto\tilde{\varphi}$, where 
$$
\tilde{\varphi}(v)=\sum_{g\in G}\varphi(g^{-1}v)g.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The dual should be $V^\ast = \hom_{\mathbb C}(V, \mathbb C)$ with $g\theta$ defined by $(g\theta)(v) = \theta(g^{-1}v)$.  Note the maps are just $\mathbb C$-linear, not $\mathbb CG$-linear so you can't pull out $g^{-1}$.

Comment: But why can't I take $R=\mathbb{C}G$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules#As_linear_maps)?

Comment: It is written that if $E$ is a $R$-module then $V^*=\operatorname{Hom}_R(E,R)$